# How can I save data in Listview when the size of it exceeds screen size?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to save or get data from `ListView` which contains `EditText`.
When I try to save or get data from `ListView` which has rows over screen size,I get the error. I know why but don't know how to fix it.the reason is they reuse the views.

Here is the example of what I want to do. If there are 5 rows in screen and 1 row out of screen , how can I get reference to the 6th row??

```
    public void saveData(){
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int count = listView.getCount();
        for(int i=0 ;i < count ;i++) {
            View child = listView.getChildAt(i);
            TextView setText1 = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            EditText text = (EditText) child.findViewById(R.id.setText1);
            String content1 = setText1.getText().toString().trim();
            String content2 = text.getText().toString().trim();
            buffer.append(content1);
            buffer.append(",");
            buffer.append(content2);
            buffer.append(",");             
   }
```

I store data in `Stringbuffer`.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> num_set ) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row  ,num_set );
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View CustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row ,parent , false);


        String[] num = getItem(position).split(",");
        TextView setText1 = (TextView)CustomView.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        EditText setText2 =(EditText)CustomView.findViewById(R.id.setText2);

        setText1.setText(num[0]);
        setText2.setText(num[1]);
        return CustomView;
    }

}
```

here is the logcat.
Caused by:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

here is the `custom_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/setText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share your adapter code.

Comment: @jankigadhiya    I did it

Comment: @PradeepGupta did it

Comment: @Indi.J Post your `custom_row.xml` code also.

Comment: @jaydroider i post it

Comment: @Indi.J Here is the problem `android:id="@+id/setText1"` is their in your `XML` and in code you have taken `R.id.setText2` change it to `R.id.setText1`. That's why it is throwing you null pointer on `findviewbyid`.

Comment: @jaydroider I changed it. But when the size of listView items exceeds screen size , it throws null pointer.maybe it is caused by recycling items.
 if we I have 5 items on screen and 1 out of screen so I can see it by scroolling,how can I get reference to the 6th item?

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

use addtext listner and save whenever you write a data in edittext so you will get specific data.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the data from the views. Because with ListViews, rows that are not on screen actually don't exist! If you type something in a row, you scroll it out of screen and in again you'll notice the text is gone.

I suggest you use something like [Arjun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37209813/1514861) to save the data in the onTextChanged somewhere. This way you can also restore the text again when scrolling in and out.

I also see you don't make any use of row re-using (using the convertView argument of the adapter). I suggest you also read into that and also into the ViewHolder pattern because you are constructing a new row every single time